# Specializing inner template with default parameters

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I'm having trouble specializing an inner template when it's parameters are all known.  Here's an example:

```
template < typename T0 >
struct outer
{
    template < typename T1 = void, typename T2 = void >
    struct inner
    {
        typedef T1 type;
    };
};
template < typename T0 >
template < typename T1 >
struct outer<T0>::inner<double,T1> { typedef int type; };
```

This works just fine.  If I instead specify the inner template like so, it does not:

```
template < typename T0 >
template < >
struct outer<T0>::inner<double,void> { typedef int type; };
```

For this I get the error message, "invalid explicit specialization before ‘>’ token...enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized...template parameters not used in partial specialization:...T0".  Not sure WTAF is going on here.

I also tried this:

```
template < typename T0 >
struct outer<T0>::inner<double,void> { typedef int type; };
```

I expected this to fail and the error message is not surprising.  It was: "too few template-parameter-lists".

So, what's the correct way to do this?  I can of course hack around it, but if I don't have to I'd prefer not.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219157/why-cant-i-specialize-the-nested-template-member-without-specializing-enclosing?lq=1

Comment: Hmm...I did do a search but that didn't show up.  Must have not sacrificed the correct species of goat before doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not allowed. You cannot fully specialize a member of a class template that has not been itself fully specialized.

Per paragraph 14.7.16 of the C++11 Standard:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears
>   in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, **except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing
>   class templates are not explicitly specialized as well**. [...]

Also, paragraph 14.7.3/15 of the C++11 Standard says:

> A member or a member template may be nested within many enclosing class templates. In an explicit
>   specialization for such a member, the member declaration shall be preceded by a `template<>` for each
>   enclosing class template that is explicitly specialized. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class T1> class A {
>      template<class T2> class B {
>          void mf();
>      };
> };
> template<> template<> class A<int>::B<double>;
> template<> template<> void A<char>::B<char>::mf();
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Comment: It's not a member function, but I suppose the same rule applies to nested types?

Comment: Assuming Nate is correct.  Can you cite chapter/verse?  03 is better, but 11 would do.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Yes, I'm looking for a quote

Comment: @CrazyEddie: I added the reference to the standard

Comment: Maybe 14.7.3/16 is more appropriate?  ("...except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well.")

Comment: Not sure about 11, but 03 has 14.7.3/18 and in it there's explicitly stated that what I'm attempting is ill-formed.  Also states, "...except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well."  Cool though, answer accepted.

Comment: @NateKohl: Yes, correct. I was just about to add that, thank you for mentioning it!

Comment: @Andy - well, it means my hack is necessary instead of just a misunderstanding on my part :P  Thanks.