# Nested class specialization in terms of outer class template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am writing a Graph class and I want to provide multiple types of graphs with the same class. More specifically, I want to consider directed or undirected graphs, as well as the possibility for vertices (and edges) to have values.

Right now, my class looks something like that.

```
template<typename VertexValue = void, typename EdgeValue = void, bool directed = false>
class Graph {
public:
    struct Vertex;
    using Edge = Vertex::Edge;

    Graph() = default;
    //void addVertex(const VertexValue& vertex);

private:
    std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
};
```

For convenience, I will skip anything related to edges implementation.

What I want to do now is to "specialize" the Vertex class to provide - or not - a value, and different methods depending on whether the graph is directed or not. I would like to be able to do something like the following (note : Vertex methods are only for illustrating purposes, directed and undirected versions of Vertex having different methods).

```
template<typename VertexValue = void, bool directed = false>
class Graph {
public:
    struct Vertex;

private:
    std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
};

// Directed, with value
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
struct Graph<VertexValue, directed>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = VertexValue;

    EdgeIterator inEdges();
    EdgeIterator outEdges();

    ValueType value;
};

// Directed, without value
template<bool directed>
struct Graph<void, directed>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = void;

    EdgeIterator inEdges();
    EdgeIterator outEdges();
};

// Undirected, with value
template<typename VertexValue>
struct Graph<VertexValue, false>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = VertexValue;

    EdgeIterator edges();

    ValueType value;
};

// Undirected, without value
template<>
struct Graph<void, false>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = void;

    EdgeIterator edges();
};
```

Unfortunately, I would have to specialize the whole Graph class in order to do that. So I tried something else : having the Vertex class being a template, and forwarding the outer template arguments.

```
template<typename VertexValue = void, bool directed = false>
class Graph {
public:
    template<typename Value, bool, typename dummy = void>
    struct Vertex;

private:
    std::vector<Vertex<VertexValue, directed>> m_vertices;
};

// Directed, with value
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
template<typename Value, bool, typename dummy>
struct Graph<VertexValue, directed>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = Value;

    EdgeIterator inEdges();
    EdgeIterator outEdges();

    ValueType value;
};

// Directed, without value
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
template<bool directed_, typename dummy>
struct Graph<VertexValue, directed>::Vertex<void, directed_, dummy> {
    using ValueType = void;

    EdgeIterator inEdges();
    EdgeIterator outEdges();
};

// Undirected, with value
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
template<typename Value, typename dummy>
struct Graph<VertexValue, directed>::Vertex<Value, false, dummy> {
    using ValueType = Value;

    EdgeIterator edges();

    ValueType value;
};

// Undirected, without value
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
template<typename dummy>
struct Graph<VertexValue, directed>::Vertex<void, false, dummy> {
    using ValueType = void;

    EdgeIterator edges();
};
```

This would work ; however, I do not like the idea of forwarding the template arguments, and it also introduces a burden, the dummy template parameter. I have also thought about defining the Vertex class outside of the Graph class, like so :

```
template<typename ValueType, bool directed>
class GraphVertex {
    EdgeIterator inEdges();
    EdgeIterator outEdges();

    ValueType value;
};

// Specializations...

template<typename Vertex = GraphVertex<void, false>>
class Graph {
public:
    // ...
private:
    std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
};
```

...or even like that :

```
template<typename ValueType, bool directed>
class GraphVertex {
    EdgeIterator inEdges();
    EdgeIterator outEdges();

    ValueType value;
};

// Specializations...

template<typename VertexValue = void, bool directed = false>
class Graph {
public:
    // ...
private:
    std::vector<GraphVertex<VertexValue, directed>> m_vertices;
};
```

...but I prefer the idea of nested class, where the Vertex class really is a property of the Graph class. Plus, even if this solution, out of the three, would still have my preference, I do not find any other name for "GraphVertex". And it bothers me.

In the end, here is my question. Is there any other way to do what I want (namely, provide different Vertex classes - or *features* - depending on the Graph template arguments) ? If so, how to and what would be the advantages ; if not, what should I prefer and why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specializing inner template with default parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129543/specializing-inner-template-with-default-parameters)

Comment: @IdeaHat This is not a duplicate at all, the three solutions I give actually work (well I am pretty sure, at least). What I am asking for are other solutions or pieces of advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your first implementation is not directly possible, because:

Paragraph 14.5.5.3/1 of the C++11 Standard

> [...] class template specialization is a distinct template. The members of the class template partial specialization **are unrelated to the members of the primary template**. [...]

This means that the member `struct Vertex` need not to exist in the partial template specialization of the class `Graph` and can thus not be defined directly, without specializing the whole class.

So, you can not do something like:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Graph { struct Vertex; };

template<typename T2> 
struct Graph<double, T2>::Vertex { };
```

(see also [Template class incomplete specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923684/template-class-incomplete-specialization))

Paragraph 14.7.3/15 of the C++11 Standard

> A member or a member template may be nested within many enclosing class templates.  In an explicit specialization for such a member, the member declaration **shall be preceded by a** `template<>` **for each enclosing class template that is explicitly specialized**

(see also [Specializing inner template with default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129543/specializing-inner-template-with-default-parameters) as indicated by IdeaHat)

This means:

```
template<typename VertexValue = void, bool directed = false>
struct Graph {
    struct Vertex;
};

// template implementation
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
struct Graph<VertexValue, directed>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = VertexValue;
};

// full specialization
template<>
struct Graph<void, false>::Vertex {
    using ValueType = void;
};
```

works fine.

### Workaround

A possible solution could be to put all the types you want to specialize into a base class of `Graph` and then specialize this base class completely:

```
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
struct BaseGraph;

template<typename VertexValue = void, bool directed = false, 
        typename Base = BaseGraph<VertexValue, directed> >
struct Graph : public Base {
    using Vertex = typename Base::Vertex;
};

// Directed, with value
template<typename VertexValue, bool directed>
struct BaseGraph {
    struct Vertex {
        using ValueType = VertexValue;
    };
};

// Directed, without value
template<bool directed>
struct BaseGraph<void, directed> {
    struct Vertex {
        using ValueType = void;
    };
};

// Undirected, with value
template<typename VertexValue>
struct BaseGraph<VertexValue, false> {
    struct Vertex {
        using ValueType = VertexValue;
    };
};

// Undirected, without value
template<>
struct BaseGraph<void, false> {
    struct Vertex {
        using ValueType = void;
    };
};
```

But this is very similar to your approach with an external GraphVertex class, that I would prefer.