# Error: Explicit specialization of 'foo' in class scope

Tags: templates, c++11, nested, traits

I am having trouble abstracting three similar functions through using template traits.

This is my code:

```
extern "C" PyObject* M_method_noargs_call_handler ( PyObject* _self_and_name_tuple, PyObject*  );
extern "C" PyObject* M_method_varargs_call_handler( PyObject* _self_and_name_tuple, PyObject* _args );
extern "C" PyObject* M_method_keyword_call_handler( PyObject* _self_and_name_tuple, PyObject* _args, PyObject* _keywords );

template<TEMPLATE_TYPENAME T>
class ExtModule : public ExtModuleBase
{
public:
    ExtModule( const char* name ) : ExtModuleBase( name ) { }
    virtual ~ExtModule() { }

protected:

    typedef std::map< std::string, MethodDefExt<T>* > method_map_t;

    using F0 = typename MethodDefExt<T>::F0;
    using F1 = typename MethodDefExt<T>::F1;
    using F2 = typename MethodDefExt<T>::F2;

    static constexpr auto& h0 = M_method_noargs_call_handler;
    static constexpr auto& h1 = M_method_varargs_call_handler;
    static constexpr auto& h2 = M_method_keyword_call_handler;

    static void add_noargs_method ( const char* name, F0 f ) { 
        methods()[ std::string(name) ] = new MethodDefExt<T>( name, f, h0 ); }

    static void add_varargs_method( const char* name, F1 f ) { 
        methods()[ std::string(name) ] = new MethodDefExt<T>( name, f, h1 ); }

    static void add_keyword_method( const char* name, F2 f ) { 
        methods()[ std::string(name) ] = new MethodDefExt<T>( name, f, h2 ); }
    :
}
```

I would like to combine all of these three methods into a single ***add_method*** with three overloads, namely for **F0** **F1** and **F2** function types.

Note that the associated handlers **h0**, **h1**, **h2** are of different types.

I've attempted to solve it using traits:

```
    template<typename>  struct h_trait;

    template<>  struct h_trait<F0> { static constexpr auto& h = h0; };
    template<>  struct h_trait<F1> { static constexpr auto& h = h1; };
    template<>  struct h_trait<F2> { static constexpr auto& h = h2; };

    template< typename F >
    static void add_method ( const char* name, F func )
    {
        methods()[ std::string(name) ] = 
                   new MethodDefExt<T>( name, func, h_trait<F>::h );
    }
```

But this is failing with:

```
Explicit specialization of 'h_trait' in class scope
```

Now **F0 F1 F2** themselves depend upon **T**, so unfortunately I can't take these traits outside of the class definition (I don't think...?)

I'm aware this is probably ludicrous over-structuring, but is there any way to accomplish this?

PS Here's MethodDefExt:

```
template<class T>
class MethodDefExt //: public PyMethodDef
{
public:
    typedef Object (T::*F0)( );
    typedef Object (T::*F1)( const Tuple& args );
    typedef Object (T::*F2)( const Tuple& args, const Dict& kws );

    // NOARGS
    MethodDefExt (
        const char* _name,
        F0 _function,
        H0 _handler
    )
    {
        meth_def.ml_name = const_cast<char *>( _name );
        meth_def.ml_meth = reinterpret_cast<PyCFunction>( _handler );
        meth_def.ml_flags = METH_NOARGS;
        f0 = _function;
    }

    // VARARGS
    MethodDefExt (
        const char* _name,
        F1 _function,
        H1 _handler
    )
    {
        meth_def.ml_name = const_cast<char *>( _name );
        meth_def.ml_meth = reinterpret_cast<PyCFunction>( _handler );
        meth_def.ml_flags = METH_VARARGS;
        f1 = _function;
    }

    // VARARGS + KEYWORD
    MethodDefExt (
        const char* _name,
        F2 _function,
        H2 _handler
    )
    {
        meth_def.ml_name = const_cast<char *>( _name );
        meth_def.ml_meth = reinterpret_cast<PyCFunction>( _handler );
        meth_def.ml_flags = METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS;
        f2 = _function;
    }

    ~MethodDefExt() { }

    PyMethodDef meth_def;

    F0 f0 = nullptr;
    F1 f1 = nullptr;
    F2 f2 = nullptr;

    Object py_method;
};
```

} // Namespace Py

Comment: I've removed my earlier comments because I was misunderstanding your question. Hopefully I do understand now: is it effectively the same as [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568046/nested-template-specialization)? If so, does the answer there work for you? And if not, can you update your question to show more clearly in what way it does not work?

Comment: Why can't you keep three separate functions you have now, but give them all the same name, `add_method`? You do want "three overloads", don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that your preferred strategy is to move h_trait outside of the class. The problem you face is that you are currently fully specializing h_trait in terms of dependent types (i.e., F0 and F1 depend on T). Since you want flexibility with your types, you might have thought to specialize in a "non-dependent" way, with something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct h_trait;

template <typename T>
struct h_trait<typename MethodDefExt<T>::F0> {...} // can't specialize this way!
```

but you'll quickly notice that T can't be deduced in this context since any old `MethodDefExt<T>` might have produced a type matching `::F0`.

We could specialize with:

```
template <>
struct h_trait<MethodDefExt<SPECIFIC_TYPE>::F0> { ... }
```

but then we have to specialize for every possible type that might be used..

So, let's mix approaches and *partially* specialize h_trait: we will deduce one template parameter, and specify the other in terms of the one deduced:

```
#include <iostream>

void h0(int) { std::cout << "h0\n"; }
void h1(int,char) { std::cout << "h1\n"; }

template <typename T> 
struct MethodDefExt { 
    typedef void(T::*F0)(int); 
    typedef void(T::*F1)(int,char); 
}; 

template <typename, typename> 
struct h_trait; 

template <typename T> 
struct h_trait<T, typename MethodDefExt<T>::F0> 
{ 
    static constexpr auto& h = h0;
}; 

template <typename T> 
struct h_trait<T, typename MethodDefExt<T>::F1> 
{ 
    static constexpr auto& h = h1;
}; 

template <typename T> 
struct YourClass { 
    using F0 = typename MethodDefExt<T>::F0;
    using F1 = typename MethodDefExt<T>::F1;

    template <typename F>
    void do_internal(F f)
    {
        h_trait<T,F> b; 
        b.h(1); // calls our awkwardly bound function just 
                // to demonstrate
    }   

    void foo() { 
        F0 f{};
        do_internal(f); // doit(F0{}); // ICE IN gcc 4.8.1
    }
};

struct A {}; 

int main() {
    YourClass<A> b; // doesn't work with non-class type parameter
    b.foo();
}
```