Specialising nested template class outside of parent class
Consider this:
#include <utility>

template<typename T> struct Outer {
    template <bool = std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>
    struct Details {
        ~Details();
    };
};


template<typename T> 
template<>
Outer<T>::Details<true>::~Details() {
    // do some stuff
}

template<typename T> 
template<>
Outer<T>::Details<false>::~Details() {
    // do some other stuff
}

Clang fires error: nested name specifier 'Outer<T>::Details<false>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization.
Is it possible to make that work without moving the implementation of Details entirely into the Outer class?

is Details required to be a template for other reasons? If not consider to implement the destructor by means of if constexpr

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568046/nested-template-specialization

@joergbrech imho related but not duplicate. I considered to post my answer over there, but its a bit far fetched to suggest if constexpr for specializations over int values.

You can use constexpr if:
#include <utility>

template<typename T> struct Outer {
    struct Details {
        ~Details();
    };
};


template<typename T> 
Outer<T>::Details::~Details() {
    if constexpr(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value) {
        // do some stuff
    } else {
        // do some other stuff
    }
}


Member template class in a template class can be specialized but it requires the outer class to be specialized first. So @463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer is perfectly fine but if you are strict with the types then you need to specialize the outer class first.

Depending on what Details is actually meant to do, it's also conceivable to make a template <typename T> struct Details outside of the Outer<T> class, to basically get around the member aspect. Still, if if constexpr is available, it's likely the best solution simply because there are no weird workarounds required.

It is similar to previous post but use c++20 concept.
As comments mention, it is to specialize outer class instead of inner class. If Outer<T> and Details are independent, using constexpr if is better.
template <class T>
concept TD = std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value;

template <class T>
concept NTD = not std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value;

template <class T>
struct Outer;

template <NTD T>
struct Outer<T> {
    struct Details {
        ~Details() {
            std::cout << "non trivially destructor" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

template <TD T>
struct Outer<T> {
    struct Details {
        ~Details() {
            std::cout << "trivially destructor" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

Live demo

you are basically suggesting to specialize the outer class instead of the nested one. Whether you then use concepts or something else is somewhat secondary. OPs approach would have worked as well when they specialize Outer and not the inner class. In other words, "Or use c++20 concept" is somewhat misleading

the difference becomes apparent once you add members to Outer that should not depend on std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value

@463035818_is_not_an_ai good point. I will change it. I think there is a bit different between constexpr if and concept. constexpr if will enforce whole details in one method but concept won't.
